# Where can I find Windows XP drivers for the HP dm3t notebook?

Tags: windows-xp, drivers

I tried Google and NotebookReview.com forums but wasn't able to find anything.

So, can anyone give me any hints?

Answer (score 1):

HP doesn't offer any XP drivers (except the for the [Qualcomm Mobile Broadband adapter and the quick launch buttons](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/softwareList?os=228&lc=en&dlc=en&cc=ie&product=4011362&lang=en)) for the HP Pavilion dm3t-1000 CTO Entertainment Notebook PC.

If you can't locate the spec sheet on HP support website, get a print out of your device manager (for more details, i recommend **[SIW](http://www.gtopala.com/download/siw.exe)**) and then start hunting down the drivers (video, audio, LAN, WLAN, etc.) from the part manufacturers' support websites.

*if you have trouble finding the drivers, feel free to update your post with the necessary information and we may assist you.*

Answer (score 1):

Are there any device drivers in particular you are after (video, sound etc)? If you go into Device Manager and post the device IDs of anything with "Unknown Device" we can help.

If it is sound in particular and you do not have Windows XP SP3 please install KB888111 and that should enable the computer to see the sound card.

For the device IDs:

This: http://www.gilsmethod.com/how_to_resolve_unknown_device_problems

And this: http://www.pcidatabase.com/

And putting them into Google normally retrieves the drivers.

Comment: "putting them into google normally retrieves drivers" ...  make that "retrieves download locations". note: if you're inexperienced, chances are that you'll end up at very fishy websites (scam, paid for downloads, malware, the works). if not sure, rather post back here and ask for assistance.

Comment: Well I'm assuming the user is capable of navigating the internet.

Comment: thanks , i didnt install the windows yet since i didnt know what i will end up with but i will install it now and tell you the result.